# FB Ads Insights API : get the access token using credentials

Tags: facebook, facebook-ads-api, facebook-marketing-api

I am new to FB's API

I need to use FB Ads Insights API to pull the stats and store in DB. This is my customer's requirement. Now, I have a Developer account and access to my customer's username and pwd, how can I use their credentials and get the access token to query Insights API

TIA,

Answer (score 0):

Use [this guide](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/audience-network/reporting-api/systemuser/) to generate an access token. You will have to create a system user that has access to your customer's account.